# How to loop through array & loop through datatable to compare values in Cypress?

Tags: arrays, foreach, datatable, cypress

In my Cypress test, I am retrieving a SQL Server DB record from a table, looping through the response, & logging each column value like so:

```
And('the below values are populated in DB ', (dataTable) => {
  cy.task('myDb', `SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerName = '${customerName}'`).then((response) => {
    response.forEach(record => {
        cy.log(record)
    });
 });
});
```

With the above code, I am logging the below array, each item in the array is a column value:

[image]

I have a datatable in my feature file that corresponds to the table structure:

```
And the below values are populated in DB
    | CustomerId | CustomerName   | AddressLine1 | AddressLine2 | City | State | Zip  |
    | 1          | Kevin Mitchell |              |              |      | NULL  | NULL |
```

What I am looking to do is update my existing code so that it can loop through my datatable & compare the above array against the datatable values in my feature file.

Can someone please explain what changes are required for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this working, & it works functionally so I'm going to post it here, but I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this.

I'm happy for someone to suggest improvements to the below answer:

```
And('the below values are populated in DB', (dataTable) => {
    cy.task('glp', `SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerName = '${customerName}'`).then((response) => {
        dataTable.rows().forEach(function ($ele) {
            response.forEach(function (record) {
                record.forEach(function(record, index) {
                    expect(record.value).to.eq($ele[index])
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```